# Python extract a browser dropdown list with selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

Dears,

I'm new using seleneium in python to do web scraping.

At this moment I have a simple example ( image attached) were I would like to extract all the countries from the dropdown list "Select Country"

I did the following code

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get(website)

wait = 20
countriesdropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dropdown"]/ul/li/a')
print(countriesdropdown)
```

but I receive something in the outbox that don't understand.

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="379a6b651a4829939ee2907a649d7655", element="3942d4ab-bb74-407a-a673-886d11fe49e9")>
```

Could you please help me the best way to do it and to learn more about web scraping using selenium in python?

thanks,
Merle-Dog

[image: html code]

[image: detail of the list]

Comment: Did my answer worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems here.

1. `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dropdown"]/ul/li/a')` returns single element, not a list as you wish.
   To get a list of web elements you should use `driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="dropdown"]/ul/li/a')`
2. when you will have a list you will have to iterate over the list elements and get their texts.
   Like this:

```py
countries = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="dropdown"]/ul/li/a')
for country in countries:
    print(country.text)
```

Comment: Thanks @Prophet , I try this solution but only print Slect Country and not the list . I attach another image to see the detail inside the dropdown.

Comment: You didn't share a link to that page so I can't know what locator will be correct

Comment: isn't a public page that's the issue :(

Comment: I understand, but it makes helping you much more difficult...